# Images are not floating on upper side of board SnakeLadder (html,css)

Tags: html, css, css-float

I want to make a layout of snake ladder game, but facing some problems. Images are not floating upper of board and using width unusually which I not want.

[My code of current layout](https://github.com/bcawallah/snake-game)

I am giving github repositories link because some problem coming when i was adding code in StackOverFlow

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .samp-sidhi {
        /* border:3px solid blue ; */
        width: 50%;
        margin: 10px auto;
        padding: 20px;
        border: 5px solid black;
      }
      .box {
        /* float: up; */
        height: 55px;
        /* float: upper; */
        border: 2px solid white;
        /* display: inline-block; */
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 600;
      }
      .box:nth-of-type(1n) {
        background-color: yellow;
      }
      .box:nth-of-type(2n) {
        background-color: rgb(141, 40, 236);
      }
      .box:nth-of-type(3n + 1) {
        background-color: rgb(16, 207, 16);
      }
      .box:nth-of-type(7n + 2) {
        background-color: rgb(235, 28, 142);
      }
      .box:nth-of-type(4n) {
        background-color: rgb(25, 127, 243);
      }
      .box:nth-of-type(7n) {
        background-color: rgb(240, 162, 18);
      }

      #ladder1 {
        float: left;
        width: 150px;
        margin-top: 11%;
        margin-left: 2.5%;
      }
      #ladder2 {
        width: 90px;
        /* margin-top: 11%; */
        margin-left: 2%;
      }
      #ladder3 {
        width: 170px;
        /* margin-top: 11%; */
        margin-left: 30%;
      }
      #snake1 {
        width: 120px;
        margin-top: 1%;
        margin-left: 20%;
      }
      #snake2 {
        width: 100px;
        margin-top: 20%;
        margin-left: 5%;
      }
      #snake3 {
        width: 220px;
        margin-top: 21%;
        margin-left: 31%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="samp-sidhi">
      <img src="/imgg/pngegg.png" alt="ladder" class="images" id="ladder1" />
      <img src="/imgg/pngegg.png" alt="ladder" class="images" id="ladder2" />
      <img src="/imgg/pngegg.png" alt="ladder" class="images" id="ladder3" />
      <img src="/imgg/snake.png" alt="snake" class="images" id="snake1" />
      <img src="/imgg/snake2.png" alt="snake" class="images" id="snake2" />
      <img src="/imgg/snake3.png" alt="snake" class="images" id="snake3" />
      <div class="box">100</div>
      <div class="box">99</div>
      <div class="box">98</div>
      <div class="box">97</div>
      <div class="box">96</div>
      <div class="box">95</div>
      <div class="box">94</div>
      <div class="box">93</div>
      <div class="box">92</div>
      <div class="box">91</div>

      <div class="box">81</div>
      <div class="box">82</div>
      <div class="box">83</div>
      <div class="box">84</div>
      <div class="box">85</div>
      <div class="box">86</div>
      <div class="box">87</div>
      <div class="box">88</div>
      <div class="box">89</div>
      <div class="box">90</div>

      <div class="box">80</div>
      <div class="box">79</div>
      <div class="box">78</div>
      <div class="box">77</div>
      <div class="box">76</div>
      <div class="box">75</div>
      <div class="box">74</div>
      <div class="box">73</div>
      <div class="box">72</div>
      <div class="box">71</div>
      <div class="box">61</div>
      <div class="box">62</div>
      <div class="box">63</div>
      <div class="box">64</div>
      <div class="box">65</div>
      <div class="box">66</div>
      <div class="box">67</div>
      <div class="box">68</div>
      <div class="box">69</div>
      <div class="box">70</div>

      <div class="box">60</div>
      <div class="box">59</div>
      <div class="box">58</div>
      <div class="box">57</div>
      <div class="box">56</div>
      <div class="box">55</div>
      <div class="box">54</div>
      <div class="box">53</div>
      <div class="box">52</div>
      <div class="box">51</div>

      <div class="box">41</div>
      <div class="box">42</div>
      <div class="box">43</div>
      <div class="box">47</div>
      <div class="box">44</div>
      <div class="box">45</div>
      <div class="box">46</div>
      <div class="box">48</div>
      <div class="box">49</div>
      <div class="box">50</div>

      <div class="box">40</div>
      <div class="box">39</div>
      <div class="box">38</div>
      <div class="box">37</div>
      <div class="box">36</div>
      <div class="box">35</div>
      <div class="box">34</div>
      <div class="box">33</div>
      <div class="box">32</div>
      <div class="box">31</div>

      <div class="box">21</div>
      <div class="box">22</div>
      <div class="box">23</div>
      <div class="box">24</div>
      <div class="box">25</div>
      <div class="box">26</div>
      <div class="box">27</div>
      <div class="box">28</div>
      <div class="box">29</div>
      <div class="box">30</div>

      <div class="box">20</div>
      <div class="box">19</div>
      <div class="box">18</div>
      <div class="box">17</div>
      <div class="box">16</div>
      <div class="box">15</div>
      <div class="box">14</div>
      <div class="box">13</div>
      <div class="box">12</div>
      <div class="box">11</div>

      <div class="box">1</div>
      <div class="box">2</div>
      <div class="box">3</div>
      <div class="box">4</div>
      <div class="box">5</div>
      <div class="box">6</div>
      <div class="box">7</div>
      <div class="box">8</div>
      <div class="box">9</div>
      <div class="box">10</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Final result looks like a snake ladder game. for example:

[image]

don't focus on layout color just fix the image right.

Comment: That's your code, right? If that's correct, you can remove the github references